# JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate, postman

I have ads-tags feature in my Spring Boot app(when user wants to create add he need to insert few tags for it). I made it as many-to-many but when I try to made API call via postman I am getting
[image]

I don't know where is problem. Maybe I don't make good body, here it is:

[image]

Here is my controller:

```
@PostMapping("/ads/create")
    public ResponseEntity<AdsDTO> newAds(@RequestHeader("Authorization") String token,@RequestBody AdsDTO adsDTO) throws ForbiddenException, BadRequestException, DynamicBadRequestException, IOException{

        return new ResponseEntity<AdsDTO>(adsServiceImplement.newAds(adsDTO, token),HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Here are entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name= "ads")
public class Ads {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "tags_ads",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ads_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tags_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Tag> adsTags;

@Entity
@Table(name="Tags")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "adsTags")
    private Set<Ads> ads;
    
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Ads> getAds() {
        return ads;
    }

    public void setAds(Set<Ads> ads) {
        this.ads = ads;
    }
```

So, what could be the problem? Am I constructuig json body wrong or something else?

Comment: You're getting a deserialization error, meaning the JSON sent by the client cannot be deserialized onto an `AdsDTO` object. I'm not sure how the entity objects were supposed to help, but please post the `AdsDTO` instead

Comment: Without seeing the DTO, we can only take an educated guess that there is an `ArrayList<...> tags` property, onto which you're trying to map the `tags: {...}` JSON fragment, which is illegal, since `{...}` is not a JSON array. If that's the case, try `tags: [{...}]` instead. Also, you might want to declare the property as a `List<...>` and let Jackson decide what collection type to instantiate